# Creating an email alert in AWS DataPipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I know AWS Data Pipeline supports and allows SNS alerts, but I want an alert or email sent if a query returns anything. Basically, I want to run a SQLActivity of a very simple select query and if that query returns anything, I want to send an email alert. Is this possible? If so, can I send the email with the returned set of data?

Answer (score 0):

No. Unfortunately, you cannot do that today with datapipeline.  The best you can do is to write a program that does what you want and execute that on a schedule using ShellCommandActivity using Datapipeline.

Comment: To add, it's also not possible to include the data directly in email.